# AWS Lambda: 'Glue' object has no attribute 'start_column_statistics_task_run'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run essentially the following code in a Lambda function:

```
client = boto3.client("glue")

response = client.start_column_statistics_task_run(
           DatabaseName=database,
           TableName=table,
           Role=glue_role)
```

The error I get is:

```
  "errorMessage": "'Glue' object has no attribute 'start_column_statistics_task_run'"
```

I checked the [required parameters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/start_column_statistics_task_run.html) and I seem to have them all. My runtime is Python 12. Moreover, I tried to look at boto3 source code in Github and I cannot find this function anywhere.

Comment: Python 12? Maybe that version of Python doesn't exist

Comment: I just tried your code on my computer and it didn't give that error. I wonder whether the version of boto3 is too old? You can use `print(boto3.__version__)` to display the version. My version is `1.34.32`.

Comment: Oh, you are right about the version. It may be too old: 1.28.72. Apparently Lambda did not upgrade its boto3.